# How to resolve GoogleSignInClient and GoogleSignIn

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In in android studio and am not able to resolve `GoogleSignInClient` and `GoogleSignIn`. I understood from similar issues that the version of '`com.google.firebase:firebase-auth`' should be set to at least '11.6.0', but the version in my app build.gradle is higher (16.0.3), as you can see:

My app build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.2'
```

My project build.gradle dependencies:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the play-services-auth version 16.0.3 in Google's release notes here - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases or even in its maven listing https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html
Change the version to 16.0.1 and com.google.firebase:firebase-auth to 16.2.0 Always keep your versions matched to latest stable releases. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your **app's gradle** .

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

and **project gradle**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

You can get your google sign in methods and objects by adding this lines .

Comment: I don't think op needs firebase-database as per the question. Also, com.google.firebase:firebase-auth: 16.2.0 should be used, the latest release version.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion. but it will solve the problem.